# How do I run everything in my Guardfile in a rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake, guard

I am using Guard in a ruby, non-rails project. (Yea, the rails tag is just there so the right people find this.)

I have a system set up that is being continually built by my Guardfile. When I run_all, all of the Guards essentially run a build, in addition to watching certain files and building selectively.

I would like to have the option to just run a build from a rake task.

I think I should be able to just do something like this in a rake task, but I don't understand what run_all expects here...

```
task :build do
  require 'guard'
  Guard.setup :guardfile => 'Guardfile'
  Guard.run_all 
end
```

Thanks for any tips...

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own lame question. I found the answer in the github wiki under "Guard Cookbook".

https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Use-Guard-programmatically-cookbook